# Pine script - How to code for this RSI Long short condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am newbie for this situation
in default RSI indicatior has 2 input RSI length and MA length

I want code for v5 pine script

Long condition is RSI Length crossover MA length

Short condition is RSI length crossunder MA length

But i don't know how to
[Image to show more clearify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haTEv.jpg)

And second question

I have Line A and line B, Line A is upper line B in pine script how to code to know line A is upper Line B

Comment: may be you misunderstand , i searched on pinescript manual v5 document and searched on other websites, but i don't see any example code for this condition. So i decide post in here. Do you have any suggestion for orientation as to which function to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your'e looking for the `ta.crossover` and `ta.crossunder` functions, which will return `true` each time one source is crossing over or under the second.

If you use the "default RSI" of TradingView, you can get the code of that indicator:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "Bollinger Bands" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

rsiLengthInput = input.int(14, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput = input.source(close, "Source", group="RSI Settings")
maTypeInput = input.string("SMA", title="MA Type", options=["SMA", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput = input.int(14, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")
bbMultInput = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="BB StdDev", group="MA Settings")

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsiMA = ma(rsi, maLengthInput, maTypeInput)
isBB = maTypeInput == "Bollinger Bands"

plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
plot(rsiMA, "RSI-based MA", color=color.yellow)
rsiUpperBand = hline(70, "RSI Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "RSI Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
rsiLowerBand = hline(30, "RSI Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(rsiUpperBand, rsiLowerBand, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="RSI Background Fill")
bbUpperBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA + ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Upper Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
bbLowerBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA - ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Lower Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
fill(bbUpperBand, bbLowerBand, color= isBB ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na, title="Bollinger Bands Background Fill")
```

To use those functions, you can for example add to this script:

```
longCondition = ta.crossover(rsi, rsiMA)
shortCondition = ta.crossunder(rsi, rsiMA)
```